# C++ vector lose heap allocated pointer

Tags: c++, rule-of-three

I wrote a simple program below for the explain.

```
class A{
public:
    int *x;

    A(){ x = 0; }
    ~A(){ delete x; }

    void foo(){
        x = new int();
        *x = 99;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<A> as;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        as.push_back(A());
        as.back().foo();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that **as** contains 3 instance of **A**.
But the pointer **x** of the first element lose its reference(written dummy value) after second **push_back** is called, and an exception is thrown at 3rd iteration.

This is resolved adding **as.reserve(3)** before for loop.

Why this happened?

Comment: You are violating the Rule of Three (or rather the Rule of Zero), and so your vector blows up when it reallocates.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I'll check it.

Comment: @KerrekSB I already know that notion(but not the term "the Rule of Three"). I think that **A()** and **as.back()** are different instances, so it's not matter because the heap allocation occurs after copy construction. I mean, **as.back()** is the element of **as**. Am I wrong?

Comment: The problem occurs in `as.push_back(A())`, which *reallocates* the internal memory, thereby *copying* the internal elements and running your broken destructor. In other words, `vector<T>` requires `T` to be copyable, but your type is not copyable since copying breaks the class invariants. (The class invariants in turn are described by the class destructor.)

Comment: Yeah, @HyunanKwon, you're almost right, but you forgot that `push_back` results in element copies too.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks all.